# HDRI is loading in wrong, how can I fix it?

Tags: hdri

I am getting HDRIs primarily from Poly Haven, which I have done before and had no issues with, but now for some reason they all load in like the image below. I've tried multiple different images, in both HDR and EXR, with no luck. I have also tried images from other sites such as hdrmaps, and the issue still persists with those.

I can turn them the right way up by changing the X rotation, but changing scale or location seems to have little or no effect. Changing the output from Texture Coordinate either makes it vanish or no change, and changing the various options in the image properties either does nothing or makes it vanish. I have noted in the image view window that the outer edges and corners of the image appear stretched, but I'm not sure if that's normal or not because I didn't pay attention to it when it was working properly.

I am running Blender 4.0.2 on Windows 10.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an *Image Texture* node, instead use a *Texture > Environment Texture*. Get your image again (see image).

With *Node Wrangler* you should be able to switch from *Image Texture* to *Environment Texture* with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> which should also keep the selected image, but *Node Wrangler* has not been updated for Blender 4 yet:

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I dragged and dropped the HDRI in thinking it would automatically detect it, as I'm following a course and that's exactly what the guy does. Is there a faster way than "Shift+A>Texture>Environment Texture>Select file path>Select image"? Can I maybe drag and drop it in then change its image type?

Comment: Enable the addon called Node Wrangler, then in the Shader Editor / World, select the Background node and press Ctrl T to get the 3 correct nodes, then in the Environment Texture click on the down arrow to select the right image

Comment: Thank you. The first time I did CTRL+T it created 7 new nodes and I deleted a lot of them, figured out I had both Background and World Output selected. That being said, I'm still having to navigate to my Download folder and locate the HDRI I want manually, as it's not appearing in the drop down menu. Is there really no easy way I can just drag and drop it in? I remember doing that before in an earlier project and it worked fine, but now it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Thanks again, sad that that's not just a built in feature. Not sure how I got it to work before, but oh well, guess this'll do for now.